# Excel load to MySQL - Performance

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, database-performance, import-from-excel

I would to insert data from excel to `MySQL` using `PHP` but I need to some validation before pushing the data to real table. I tried 2 option and both option works for me.

**Option 1**
Read the excel data in the array. Loop the array, fetch each value and do the validation on the data. Then insert into the real table. **OR**
**Option 2**
Bulk load the data to temp table in db. Call a procedure and and do the proper validation. Once validation done, move the data from temp table to real table.

I know both option is achievable but I more concern on the performance. Did anyone know which one is better in performance. In other word, can execute faster. Any advice or reference links are highly appreciated.

Comment: Option 2 will be faster.

Comment: It's impossible to answer without knowing what kind of validations you have to make.

Comment: Option #3.... if possible, read the Excel data a row at a time, validate and insert to the database..... saves all the memory overheads of building an array in memory. Using prepared statements also helps, because you only need to prepare the statement once, and just bind the variables for each insert

Comment: @SuryaElite may i know why you saying option 2 faster

Comment: @rlanvin just normal validation.. check null value.. min value.. basic validaton

Comment: @MarkBaker my excel contains more than 10k of rows, which having up 10 columns. Do you how I can read the entire excel at at time using PHP. Please advice.

Comment: I recommended that you __don't__ read the entire Excel in one go

Comment: @chinna_82 I said that because, running procedure on table is faster than reading a file which is huge set of data then applying the rules set to clean it. That will also consume lot of memory in php. You can use php array iterator if you want to read a single row and process it to consume less memory.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if validating your Excel data row per row will be faster, but it will save you from arrays stored in memory.

Fetch Excel row -> validate row -> insert into db

I personally don't like bulk inserts.

Comment: Mark Baker beat me to it in a comment.

Comment: I'm having more than 10k or rows. You suggesting me to read excel and validate all the rows one by one?

Comment: @chinna_82 That's exactly what they are suggesting, and it is a very solid approach, as long as your validations only requires one row at the time.

Comment: @chinna_82 The suggestion is not all that different from your option one, you're just not storing in an array (a good thing) and you are not inserting data in bulk (definitely a good thing)

Answer (score 0):

If you want speed, do not handle one row at a time.  Instead, use what SQL is good at -- applying the same thing to an array (table) of values.

Let's say you want to turn empty strings into NULLs for column `foo`.  This will do that for the entire table:

```
UPDATE tbl SET foo = NULL  WHERE foo = '';
```

Simple.  Fast.  Very efficient.

Remove dollar signs and comas from numbers.  Eg, `$1,234.56` --> `1234.56`.

1. Read into a `VARCHAR`, not a numeric field.
2. Have (or add) a column with the numeric field, say `DECIMAL(11,2)`.

Then,

```
UPDATE tbl SET amt = REPLACE(REPLACE(amt_str, ',', ''), '$', '');
```

If you are using `LOAD DATA`, you can do both of these examples inside the statement.  (And avoid the extra column.)